# How do we measure the size (not mass but dimensions) of far away galaxies?

Tags: astronomy, stars, distance

I understand how distances to galaxies are measured. I think I  even understand how their mass might be measured (by their orbital trajectories?). But how can we know How big far away stars are? Like stars that are millions of light years away.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nearby galaxies have an observable size in a telescope. If you know how far away a galaxy is and you can measure its observable size then you can calculate its actual size.

Stars in other galaxies and very distant galaxies themselves are just points of light. But we can estimate their size by finding a nearby star or galaxy with a similar luminosity and spectrum (corrected for red shift) and using that as a proxy.

This method does not work if there are no nearby examples of the object being studied, which is why it took astronomers  so long to establish the nature of quasars.

Comment: thank you. are the sizes changing? if the universe is expanding, then stars further away should look larger than 'identical' stars closer to us(because their light which is just reaching us now started when they were a lot closer, whereas the closer stars have not experienced as much spatial expansion).